# The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory

Tags: java, windows, maven

I'm facing below exception:

> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.MissingProjectException: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.

Console log:

```
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.5\conf\settings.xml 
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\user_aaa\.m2\settings.xml 
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\path\to\local\repo 
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\path\to\local\repo 
[INFO] Scanning for projects... 
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:pom:1: (none) 
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.078 s 
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-12T17:05:08+08:00 
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/123M 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.MissingProjectException: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.
```

Maven version info:

```
C:\>mvn -X version 
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-15T01:29:23+08:00) 
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.5 
Java version: 1.8.0_144, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre 
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MS950_HKSCS
OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

Do I need to set `pom.xml` by myself? How and where? Did I install Maven correctly in Windows?

Comment: Yes, you need to configure your pom.xml by yourself. Check google on how to do it - it is pretty easy

Comment: where I should put it?

Comment: From nullpointer's answer -> https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_make_my_first_Maven_project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to find the version of `maven` is

```
mvn -X -version
```

though `-X` is a debug option and is redundant here.

In case you want to execute a project.

> do I need to set pom.xml by myself? How and where?

You create a `pom.xml` within a maven based project at the top level directory. The [first maven project sample](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_make_my_first_Maven_project)  shall help you further here.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the current directory that you execute the mvn command does not include a pom.xml
Just change your current dir to where your pom resides and execute mvn command there.

Comment: do you mean I need to project first?

Comment: Are you trying to (1) just compile an already existing project or (2) create a new one? If (1) the project will already have a pom file if it is a maven project, if (2) yes, you need to create a pom.xml. don't do it yourself, use new maven project feature of your favorite IDE (e.g. IntelliJ Idea or Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Maven (download apache-maven-3.9.1-bin.zip)
2. Ungip apache-maven-3.9.1-bin.zip
3. Set the environment variable
   export M2_HOME=/Applications/apache-maven-3.9.1
   export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
4. mvn -X -version
5. Go to your project location where pom.xml is there
6. mvn clean
   [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
7. mvn compile
   [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
8. mvn test